# How to connect with passwords that contains characters like "$" or "@"?

Tags: python, mysql, passwords

I cannot get a connection to a MySQL database if my password contains punctuation characters in particular `$` or `@`.  I have tried to escape the characters, by doubling the `$$` etc. but no joy.

I have tried the `pymysql` library and the `_mssql` library.

the code... 
self.dbConn = _mysql.connect(host=self.dbDetails['site'], port=self.dbDetails['port'], user=self.dbDetails['user'], passwd=self.dbDetails['passwd'], db=self.dbDetails['db'])

where self.dbDetails['passwd'] = "$abcdef".

I have tried '$$abcdef', and re.escape(self.dbDetails['passwd']), and '\$abcdef' but nothing works until I change the users password to remove the "$". Then it connects just fine. The only error I am getting is a failure to connect. I guess I will have to figure out how to print the actual exception message.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you show the specific code you have tried?

Comment: The backslash `\\` character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning in python

Comment: welcome to SO.Did you get any error message if you are using escape characters?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You should try doing it right. Hard to be more specific unless you are.

Comment: the code...         self.dbConn = _mysql.connect(host=self.dbDetails['site'], port=self.dbDetails['port'], user=self.dbDetails['user'], passwd=self.dbDetails['passwd'], db=self.dbDetails['db'])
  where self.dbDetails['passwd'] = "$abcdef".  I have tried '$$abcdef', and re.escape(self.dbDetails['passwd']), and '\$abcdef' but nothing works until I change the users password to remove the "$".  Then it connects just fine.  The only error I am getting is a failure to connect.  I guess I will have to figure out how to print the actual exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to MySQLdb package, you can punctuation in password to connect database through this package.